# Using Self-Signed Certificates in local Node.js/Express/React development

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

The question deals with using self-signed certificates in local full-stack (in this case React application and Node.js FE server) development.

**Note** that the question itself is probably not as complex as the length of it would suggest. Simply, I needed to describe the entire setup to avoid dealing with non-relevant trivial suggestions. Also, when/if the question is answered, it should serve as a nice starting point for such endeavours.

**Reason**

Many features, including but not limited to *shared* signed cookies, http2, etc..., work only over HTTPS or require sibling/parent domain setup, which brings forward the need to create a certificate and run both Webpack Dev Server and Nodejs FE server over HTTPS (locally) on explict domains and not on `localhost`.

*Note* that the problem is specific to the local development, as it is properly configured with non-self-signed certificates and over HTTPS in production.

**Assumption**

While it is possible to create a "normal" certificate using something like Let's Encrypt, it is not always possible or desirable (company policies or some such).

For this reason, and for sheer academic purposes, we choose to use *self-signed certificate*.

**Setup**

OS: Mac Catalina 10.15.2
Node: 13.8

There are two sub-domains:

- `app.mylocaldomain.com` which hosts the React application via Webpack Dev Server
- `api.mylocaldomain.com` which hosts the FE API server via Node.js + Express

**Need**

Be able to make an HTTPS AJAX request from `https://app.mylocaldomain.com` to `https://api.mylocaldomain.com/some-route`

**Steps**

1. Add `app.mylocaldomain.com` and `app.mylocaldomain.com` to `/etc/hosts`

   ```
   ...
   127.0.0.1   api.mylocaldomain.com
   127.0.0.1   app.mylocaldomain.com
   ...
   ```
2. Create `api/req.cnf` file

   ```
   [req]
   distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
   x509_extensions = v3_req
   prompt = no
   [req_distinguished_name]
   C = US
   ST = State
   L = Location
   O = myorg
   OU = myunit 
   CN = api.mylocaldomain.com
   [v3_req]
   keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
   extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
   subjectAltName = @alt_names
   [alt_names]
   DNS.1 = api.mylocaldomain.com
   ```
3. Create `app/req.cnf` file

   ```
   [req]
   distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
   x509_extensions = v3_req
   prompt = no
   [req_distinguished_name]
   C = US
   ST = State
   L = Location
   O = myorg
   OU = myunit 
   CN = app.mylocaldomain.com
   [v3_req]
   keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
   extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
   subjectAltName = @alt_names
   [alt_names]
   DNS.1 = app.mylocaldomain.com
   ```
4. Create **App** `cert.key` and `cert.pem` files:

   ```
   openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
   -keyout app/cert.key -out app/cert.pem -config app/req.cnf -sha256
   ```
5. Create **API** `cert.key` and `cert.pem` files:

   ```
   openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
   -keyout api/cert.key -out api/cert.pem -config api/req.cnf -sha256
   ```
6. Load both certificates to Mac Keychain Access and approve both to be trusted

   This is the working result with both certificates approved in keychain:

   [image]
7. Configure the application Webpack Dev Server to start over HTTPS

   ```js
   devServer: {
       ...
       host: 'app.mylocaldomain.com',
       port: 443,
       https: {
           key: FS.readFileSync('/path/to/app/cert.key'),
           cert: FS.readFileSync('/path/to/app/cert.pem')
       },
       ...
   }
   ```
8. Start the application with `sudo yarn start` (`webpack-dev-server` in npm scripts) to allow using `443` port

   This is the working result:

   [image]

   where the application is properly loaded over HTTPS.

   *Note* that omitting `sudo` causes the following (or similar, depending on your Webpack Dev Server setup):

   ```
   ...
   Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:443
   ...
   ```
9. Configure the FE server to start over HTTPS

   ```
   ...
   const app = express(...)
   ...
   const key = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/api/cert.key');
   const cert = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/api/cert.pem');

   https.createServer({key, cert}, app).listen(PORT, error => {
       if (!error) {
           console.info(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`);
       } else {
           console.error(error);
       }
   });
   ...
   ```
10. Start the FE API server using `sudo yarn start --open --public api.mylocaldomain.com --port 443` (`node lib/` in npm scripts)

    ```
    yarn run v1.22.0
    $ node lib/ --public api.mylocaldomain.com
    Listening on port: 5000
    ```

---

**Problem**

The above setup should have been enough, however, invoking an AJAX request to `https://api.mylocaldomain.com/status` (yes, the route exists) causes the following (abridged for clarity) error in Chrome console:

```
GET https://api.mylocaldomain.com/status
net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

If you were to access `https://api.mylocaldomain.com/status` directly in Chrome, you'd get the following:

[image]

**This would suggest that the certificates for App and API got somehow mixed**, but I ran the above steps in various permutations multiple times and fail to see how that would happen. Perhaps `/etc/hosts` mapping mucks this up? Would make sense, since both `app.` and `api.` are mapped into `127.0.0.1` creating the mixup. However, I am conflicted as to how resolve this.

Indeed, if inspected, it seems that Chrome (at least) loads App certificate when API is accessed. Why?

Following the link above leads to:

[image]

Invoking `curl -XGET https://api.mylocaldomain.com/status` causes the following error:

```
>>> curl -XGET https://api.mylocaldomain.com/status
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.mylocaldomain.com'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

which is odd, as `api.mylocaldomain.com` is explicitly defined in the `req.cnf` for the API above.

---

**Suggestions?**

I assume that this is something extremely minuscule and I will feel embarrassed for having missed it, but after multiple passes and re-tries, it may have entered into my blind spot(s).

**Appendix A.**

Creating a multi-domain `*.mylocaldomain.com` certificate doesn't work either, with the error being 'invalid common name' or `Invalid Host header` depending on various setting permutations.

Comment: `Many features, including but not limited to signed cookies`  You might not know this and might simplify things for you.  `localhost` over port 80 is classed as secure origin too, so for things that require SSL will work on localhost over HTTP too without even having to create a self signed cert.

Comment: @Keith I am aware of this, however, in order to do shared signed cookies (which was the entire point) you need to have HTTPS and sibling domains -- which can't be done over `localhost`, as port is a part of 3rd party domain definition, thus not allowing you to have app at `localhost:3000` and API at `localhost:5000` and having the cookies be shared properly. Finally, HTTP2 doesn't work without HTTPS in Webpack AFAIK (but that's for our future uses and is not central to this). 

However -- amended the OP. thank you.

Comment: Ok, we do similar stuff.  We have single wildcard domain, this is a proper domain so no need to mess about with host files / but you still can if say you wanted to use firewall IP's.  We just then create lots of `A` records like `app1` ,`app2` etc,.  or even specific ones if logical.  If your worried about cost of getting a wildcard domain is an issue, letsencrypt now supports wildcards.  Finally stick this behind a reverse proxy.

Comment: In the long run this is much better than messing with self signed certs, because even when you do get this working, it still has issues.  eg. in Chrome ajax / fetch responses will silently start failing because Chrome periodically wants you to re-confirm the self signed cert.

Comment: @Keith you don't need to reconfirm them AFAIK since they are in the keychain. On Windows -- 100% you need to. You are probably right, but it has been started in this direction and I'd like to see it through.